# Symfony4. To use monolog or not to use?

Tags: symfony4, monolog

I need for my project a logger to log some events, like sending of confirmation e-mails, transitions in the workflow etc. It's not about what happens in the doctrine, form etc (dev.log)

Is the using of monolog the right way for my issue?

Answer (score 0):

In one hand, a library like monolog will provides your app a systematic approach for events' logging, handlers on event (preLog, postLog, ...), functionnalities, etc. But it has cost (CPU, RAM, integration in design, ...).

In other hand, writing a line in a file is really simple and has no additionnal cost.

So, the point is to know how much large is your project and what are yours priorities (speed, readibility, memory size).